# Flutter web stop using Ctrl+Shift+R

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

Hello I have a Flutter web app, it works with firebase hosting and firebase database. Every time I deploy  a new version from Android Studio, it deploys, it uploads it and the changes can be seen from the firebase console. However when I go to my website I have to manually press ctrl+shift+r for it to update to the latest version. So is there a solution to this? Will the website update within hours by itself or it will never update unless you do the combination with the 3 keys. It's an app that already has users so I just fixed a few bugs but the changes cant be seen. Thank you!

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+R reloads the web page... works as expected

Comment: but for a user that already opened the app and doesnt know this he will not get the latest version

Comment: yep until they reload... else you can implement some reload "mechanism"

Comment: @griffins how could I do that, does flutter have it or it's tech outside of flutter that I must implement?

Comment: you will have to implement this.,Assuming you're storing a version of your web app somewhere you can set listeners to it such that if it changes you reload the webpage

Comment: I think it is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59640787/refresh-build-deployed-on-firebase-hosting-on-changing-route-or-detecting-new-bu) Correct if I am wrong

Comment: Not sure if this is correct, but this may be due to the service worker Flutter creates for you to enable faster loading and offline usage. Although this video is anecdotal (vs a tutorial), it does a great job at explaining what he went through: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJSloXLTyNg

Answer (score 1):

I believe the flutter web team are looking into a "auto cache flush" mechanism for Flutter Web, but haven't seen anything yet. Easiest way to have a continuous development cycle for Flutter Web would be to remove the cache, but it will impact performance, depending on your application.

Add this code to your `<head> </head>` tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```